# Entity Framework reverse poco on table without primary key and null column

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, poco

I am using Entity Framework Reverse POCO generator v2.37.5.

I need to map an external database. It is not possible for me modify the schema. But the tables don't have primary key and all columns are set to null.

However, the combination of certain columns will always be unique.
For example, the following 3 columns can be combine to form the primary key:

- EnrollNumb
- CubNumb
- SeqVal

[image]

Is there any setting in the template that helps me to set combination of columns as primary key?

Any suggestion / direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I am using Entity Framework Reverse POCO generator v2.37.5." - neat, I worked on that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First, find your `Entities.ttinclude` file.

   - <sub>Protip / **entirely optional side-quest and distraction** for better T4 editing:</sub>

     - <sub>Extract all the C# code (inside the T4 `<#+ #>` blocks) and move it to a new file named `Entities.ttinclude.cs`</sub>
     - <sub>Add `<#@ Include File = "Entities.ttinclude.cs" #>` to the `Entities.ttinclude` file.</sub>
     - <sub>Change the project build-action for `Entities.ttinclude.cs` to `None`.</sub>
     - <sub>Now you can get (basic) syntax-coloring for the C# code.</sub>
     - Now back to your regularly scheduled stackoverflowing:
2. Look for this somewhere around lines 250-320:

   ```
   Settings.UpdateColumn = (Column column, Table table) =>
   ```
3. Inside the function you can tell EF that *there totally is a PK defined on this table, I pinky-swear!* like so:

   ```
   Settings.UpdateColumn = (Column column, Table table) => 
   {
       // ...

       if( column.ParentTable.Name == "Memb" )
       {
           switch( column.Name )
           {
           case "EnrollNumb":
           case "CubNumb":
           case "SeqVal":

               column.IsNullable        = false; // PK columns cannot be NULLable.
               column.IsPrimaryKey      = true;
               column.PrimaryKeyOrdinal = column.Ordinal;

               column.ParentTable.HasPrimaryKey = true

               break;
           }
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```
4. Run `Model.tt`
5. Assuming no errors happened, take a look at the folder with the generated `.cs` files, look for `Memb.Configuration.cs`. It should look  something like this:

   ```
   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("EF.Reverse.POCO.Generator", "2.37.1.0")]
   internal class MembConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Memb>
   {
       public MembConfiguration( String schema )
       {
           ToTable( "Memb", schema );
           HasKey( x => new { x.EnrollNumb, x.CubNumb, x.SeqVal } );

           Property( x => x.EnrollNumb ).HasColumnName( "EnrollNumb" ).HasColumnType( "nvarchar" ).IsRequired().MaxLength(10);
           Property( x => x.CubNumb    ).HasColumnName( "CubNumb"    ).HasColumnType( "nvarchar" ).IsRequired().MaxLength(50);
           Property( x => x.SeqVal     ).HasColumnName( "SeqVal"     ).HasColumnType( "nvarchar" ).IsRequired().MaxLength(5);

           // other columns here
       }
   }
   ```
6. And you should be able to build your project, then run it, and it should *just work*.

---

You can also define *fake* Foreign Key constraints and set-up other kinds of relationships and *EF will believe you*, which is handy for when you want EF to handle a `VIEW` as though it were a `TABLE`, especially as a `VIEW` in SQL Server cannot be imbued with PK and FK constraints (you can also get DML working provided your `VIEW` is updatable).

Comment: Thank for the detail steps. Let me try. Quick question though... Is the step 1 mandatory?

Comment: @JGV Please quote the instruction you're interpreting as "Step 1"

Comment: Sure, in your answer you mentioned, 1. First, find your Entities.ttinclude file...  and the bullet points that follows. I am referring to that.

Comment: @JGV Ah, no - that's entirely optional (see where it says "side-quest"). You can skip those bullets.

Comment: Thank you. I tried and the Memb.Configuration.cs is not generated. 
I have another quick question though, In Step 3, which starts with "Inside the function you can tell EF that there totally is a PK defined on this table, I pinky-swear! like so:" you are setting IsPrimaryKey = true twice. Is that intentional? (column.IsPrimaryKey      = true;
            column.IsNullable        = false; // PK columns cannot be NULLable.
            column.IsPrimaryKey      = true;

Comment: It is working now. Along with the code you have provided, I added the following: column.ParentTable.HasPrimaryKey = true; and it worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JGV The duplicate `IsPrimaryKey = true` line was a typo. Thank you. I've removed it.